# How can I check the API response of an activity in android Espresso?

Tags: android, android-espresso

I want to test the volley api response using android espresso. In my activity I am getting the API response with success and error callbacks. But I couldn't get, how to check the response from api is passed or failed callback.

Comment: do share some codes, would be better to understand your need

Comment: That is one login activity, where the username and password entered automatically with espresso and login button click function triggered. When I try to run the testcase the activity opened and type the username and password, login button click operation performs and the activity is closed.

I tried with idling resource increment and decrement for api call now it's working fine. But I don't get exactly the operation is failed or completed.